# Excel Data Validated List Not Triggering Calculate When Changed

Tags: excel, office365

I have a bit of time series data, and potentially want to do a calculation on it. I allow a user to decide if the calculation should be done.

To achieve this, I have a cell that applies data validation to restrict its options to 'Yes' and 'No'. Then I use a conditional that just duplicates the source data, in an adjacent column, if the drop down is toggled to 'No'. If toggled to 'Yes' a lengthy function is applied. For example, `=if($AO$9='No', B3, B3 *` ***some long function***`)`, where AO9 contains the toggle and this would be entered in C3 and then extended the length of column B.

When toggled from 'No' to 'Yes' the sheet doesn't automatically recalculate. The odd thing is, if I modify ***any*** other cell subsequent to toggling between 'No' and 'Yes' it updates instantly and uses the appropriate condition. Additionally, after toggling the cell, if I click in and out of the formula bar it also updates appropriately. Neither of these are ideal solutions when there are other people working on this book. I've checked all of the usual suspects (i.e., calculation options set to automatic, proof below, and that the toggle cell is set to type general and not text).

[image: Calculation Option]

I've used this sort of scheme for a long time to allow user interaction, and have never had a problem. I did however just upgrade to 365 (Version 1802 Build 9029.2253). Has anyone else encountered this? If so, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kept a lot of details super-secret but I would propose a Worksheet_Change event sub procedure that forces B3 to recalculate.

In B3's parent worksheet's private code sheet,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AO9")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B3").Calculate
    End If
meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Failing that, just use INDIRECT or OFFSET inside the super-secret 'long formula' and it will recalculate whenever anything in any open workbook changes.

Comment: would a +now()-now() at the end of the formula have the same effect as indirect / offset? and there is a small chance it's easier to understand

Comment: @jeeped Thank you for the suggestion, and sorry about the ambiguity in the 'long formula' bit. It has a bunch of irrelevant stuff in it and I didn't want anyone to get spun off on something bogus. The worksheet function seems a bit overkill, but the volatile is a pretty easy solution. So thank you! Just out of curiosity I would love to know which has more overhead the volatile or a change event (downstream calculations aside).

Comment: @LJ01 - Take any valid cell reference like `'sheet one'!a1` and change it to `INDIRECT("'sheet one'!a1")`.

Comment: The volatile method has **much** more calculation lag since a volatile function will recalculate whenever **anything** in any open workbook changes.

Comment: @LJ01 - ... but yes, either now()-now() or today()-today() should do the same for a maths operation.